# Why does PySpark not find spark-submit when creating a SparkSession?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to initialize a PySpark cluster with a Jupyter Notebook on my local machine running Linux Mint. I am following [this tutorial](https://opensource.com/article/18/11/pyspark-jupyter-notebook). When I try to create a SparkSession, I get an error that `spark-submit` does not exist. Strangely, this is the same error I get when I try to get the version of `spark-shell` without including `sudo`.

```
spark1 = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test').getOrCreate()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/./bin/spark-submit'
```

The correct directory for `spark-submit` is

`'~/Spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/bin/spark-submit'` (without the extra `./`, but the former directory should still be valid, right?)

I don't know where Spark is getting this directory from, so I don't know where to correct it.

As mentioned, I cannot even get the version of spark-shell without including `sudo`:

```
~/Spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/bin$ ./spark-shell --version
./spark-shell: line 60: ~/Spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory

~/Spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/bin$ ls | grep spark-submit
spark-submit
spark-submit2.cmd
spark-submit.cmd

~/Spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/bin$ sudo ./spark-shell --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.2
      /_/
                        
Using Scala version 2.12.10, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.11
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user centos on 2021-05-24T04:27:48Z
Revision de351e30a90dd988b133b3d00fa6218bfcaba8b8
Url https://github.com/apache/spark
Type --help for more information.
```

I tried allowing read, write, and execute permissions to all of the files in `~/Spark` with no effect.
Could this be related to Java permissions?

My `.bashrc` looks like this:

```
export SPARK_HOME='~/Spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2'
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME:$PATH:~/.local/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
```

I'm using Python 3.8 and the Apache Spark 3.1.2 pre-built with Hadoop 3.2. My Java version is openjdk 11

Edit: After reinstalling (without modifying the permissions), the files in `~/Spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/bin/` are:

```
$ ls -al ~/Spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/bin
total 124
drwxr-xr-x  2 squid squid  4096 May 23 21:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 squid squid  4096 May 23 21:45 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 squid squid  1089 May 23 21:45 beeline
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1064 May 23 21:45 beeline.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 squid squid 10965 May 23 21:45 docker-image-tool.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 squid squid  1935 May 23 21:45 find-spark-home
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  2685 May 23 21:45 find-spark-home.cmd
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  2337 May 23 21:45 load-spark-env.cmd
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  2435 May 23 21:45 load-spark-env.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 squid squid  2634 May 23 21:45 pyspark
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1540 May 23 21:45 pyspark2.cmd
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1170 May 23 21:45 pyspark.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 squid squid  1030 May 23 21:45 run-example
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1223 May 23 21:45 run-example.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 squid squid  3539 May 23 21:45 spark-class
-rwxr-xr-x  1 squid squid  2812 May 23 21:45 spark-class2.cmd
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1180 May 23 21:45 spark-class.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 squid squid  1039 May 23 21:45 sparkR
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1097 May 23 21:45 sparkR2.cmd
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1168 May 23 21:45 sparkR.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 squid squid  3122 May 23 21:45 spark-shell
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1818 May 23 21:45 spark-shell2.cmd
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1178 May 23 21:45 spark-shell.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 squid squid  1065 May 23 21:45 spark-sql
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1118 May 23 21:45 spark-sql2.cmd
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1173 May 23 21:45 spark-sql.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x  1 squid squid  1040 May 23 21:45 spark-submit
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1155 May 23 21:45 spark-submit2.cmd
-rw-r--r--  1 squid squid  1180 May 23 21:45 spark-submit.cmd
```

Comment: Could you show output of ~/Spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/bin?

Comment: I meant: ls -al ~/Spark/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/bin

Answer (score 0):

Why does 'squid' have ownership of all these files? Can you set the user/ group ownership to the user that is used to run these submits and therefore needs all these environment variables defined in .bashrc

Comment: I don't understand. Why wouldn't I? I'm just downloading `spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz` from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html and extracting it in this folder, so I have ownership.

Comment: Please change the ownership as mentioned previously and try running spark submit.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound really stupid, but I was having exactly the same problem using a custom Pyspark Kernel for jupyter notebook. What solved it was changing the "~" in spark path to "/home/{user}".
Here's how my Kernel looks like

```
{
"display_name": "PySpark",
"language": "python",
"argv": [
    "/usr/bin/python3",
    "-m",
    "ipykernel",
    "-f",
    "{connection_file}"
],
"env": {
    "SPARK_HOME": "/home/rafael/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/",
    "PYTHONPATH": "/home/rafael/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/:~/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip",
    "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/home/rafael/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/shell.py",
    "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--master local[*] --conf spark.executor.cores=1 --conf spark.executor.memory=512m pyspark-shell"
}
```

}